# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Android studio

Tags: android

..

I am facing an error as Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\ankur\AndroidStudioProjects\source1\app\src\main\res\values\public.xml: Error: Found item ###/icon more than one time

I tried to remove the icon mentioned from public.xml but it does not work

Comment: Please see my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66520627/11142666

Answer (score 0):

Relocate your project and the build will succeed.

I have done the following changes in a similar issue of mine:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.3'
}
```

I have not seen any more mergeDebugResource issues when running my project. Hope this helps!

**Note**: To stay up to date with Gradle you can change the version number to 0.4.+

Answer (score 0):

Remove the copy of the items which is present more than one time.
you can do it as follows:-

```
-in android studio go to res>>values>>Strings.xml
-then remove the item which is underlined red(delete a line and then wait for it to refresh )
-then rebuild your project.
```