# Execution failed for taskmergeDebugResources in android Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, import

[[image: Execution failed for task message]]

This is the error that appears when trying to build the project that was imported from Eclipse to Android Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task 'app:mergeDebugResources' Crunching Cruncher....png failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa)

Comment: @AmarAgrawal no dude that's not the issue here.