# why i get Some file crunching failed after i rename drawable file to .9.png?

Tags: android

I am testing 9-patch image .
Before everything works fine , and i rename `drawable` file `ic_button_beat_box_default.png` to `ic_button_beat_box_default.9.png` , then i get error :

> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

. Then i rename back , it works normal. So how this happens ?

The complete error is :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.waitForAll(QueuedCruncher.java:260)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.end(QueuedCruncher.java:280)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:132)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:291)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doIncrementalTaskAction(MergeResources.java:250)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task 'app:mergeDebugResources' Crunching Cruncher....png failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa)

Comment: I have problem Like that, and check the origin format of picture and change it with the origin fotmat is jpeg

Answer (score 39, accepted):

On Windows I had a "BUILD FAILED Failed to crunch file [path]" error and solved it by closing the Android Studio project, copying the entire project folder into a location with a shorter directory path, such as my C: folder and then opening the project in the new location. Hope it helps

Comment: This has to do with Windows path length limits when Bamboo is running on Windows Server. Solution: Build on Linux!

Answer (score 3):

Rename your file again

`ic_button_beat_box_default.9.png`  to `ic_button_beat_box_default9.png` because android studio takes `ic_button_beat_box_default.9` instead of `ic_button_beat_box_default.9.png`

or another solution is add below line to your build.gradle(Module:app)

```
android{
 aaptOptions {cruncherEnabled = false} 
}
```

Comment: +1 for writing the `android {...}` key. I am a react-native developer and know little about `build.gradle` structure

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue by changing only file name, when I saved the image in 9-patch-tool issue solved.

Comment: Same solution as mine using macOS. I just renamed bla.png to bla.9.png, then I opened it in android studio, modified in built-in editor and saved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was able to resolve it just by reducing one folder from chain. It is due to long file path. So try using minimum hierarchy for your project location.

Answer (score 1):

try this, insert this code in android section in app gradle:

```
aaptOptions {  
    cruncherEnabled = false  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have red  other similar questions and answers to them on SO, regarding that "file crunching failed, see logs for details" error.
Nothing helped.So,I reverted all "SO" changes I made with gradle and other  files 
and removed ".9" in that png.9 files and it began work.
Then I recreated  all *.9.png files again. 
Hence, in my case the cause was wrong editing of 9.pngs in external png editors.

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was to set

```
aaptOptions {  
    cruncherEnabled = false  
}
```

Then to run the app (icons were missing) 
then remove this option and run the app again.
Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Build -> Clean Project.

and then

Build -> Rebuild Project.