# How fix Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a project in Eclipse and I export to gradle project and open in Android Studio when I sync project I get 
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

This is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smok.maps"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/osmbonuspack_v4.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-4.2-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I got this issue because my project was imported from Eclipse to Android Studio and dependencies were missing in gradle.

I got rid of it after adding

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

in

```
defaultConfig {
}
```

below

```
targetSdkVersion 25
```

After, this I had to set

```
minSdkVersion 9
```

Also, I added following lines

```
aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
```

above

```
defaultConfig {
    //code snippet
}
```

So, that it looks like,

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        }
        //remaining code snippet
        //.....
    }
    //remaining code snippet
    //.....
}
```

@tompok, you are getting this error maybe due to jar files you are using in dependencies may not be there.

Instead Google for their gradle dependencies and place the package name in place of path like it is in first line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
```

Replace remaining dependencies in the above format.

Hope, it will help you.

**______________________________________**

**EDIT:**

You are facing this problem since you are using `buildToolsVersion 25.0.2` whereas library you are using is `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'`

Just change it to `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.2'` and your issue will be solved.

Ask if you face any other issue else accept it as answer so it may help others.

Answer (score 4):

Try code on your module build.gradle:

```
 android {
 // ...
 aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
 aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
 // ...
 }
```

**It means Android studio DO NOT check PNG strictly.**

Answer (score 4):

I met this problem, after draw the left and bottom stratch line  for .9
.png   then it  ok. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

most of the time is a corrupt PNG image added recently to the project which cause this error.
Check the git log and replace the file.

Sometimes menu : `File > InvalidateCaches/Restart also helps`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I didn't got the solution when I used in android studio 3.1

```
android {
 // ...
 aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
 aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
 // ...
 }
```

Actually I'm in the process of importing the eclipse project to latest android studio. I spend around three day in searching for this specific error.

```
 Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

I found some references from the following links...

- [why i get Some file crunching failed after i rename drawable file to .9.png?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477333/why-i-get-some-file-crunching-failed-after-i-rename-drawable-file-to-9-png)
- [Gradle throw app:mergedebugresources exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207861/gradle-throw-appmergedebugresources-exception/41218464)

After that I searched In the **drawable** for the images with the extension `image_name.9.png`. and **renamed** it to `image_name.png`. After that this error got disappeared. Again this worked for my project, still not sure about other causes for this problem. I hope that this may be useful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate the caches then close the project and import it again.