# Cannot get a build after build versions changed

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a legacy project with almost a huge number of dependencies for which I cannot get a build from Gradle.

Here is the errors I get (for which I searched the SOF and came accross these answers none of which worked for me:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479407/how-fix-errorjava-util-concurrent-executionexception-com-android-ide-common-pr)

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301203/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-androidkeyboardnavigationc)

I have tried backwarding the buildTools version and sdk versions. Nothing has worked.

Here are the errors I get:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :sidemenulibrary:generateDebugSources, :sidemenulibrary:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :sidemenulibrary:mockableAndroidJar]
C:\Users\Farzin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-11.8.0.aar\816b583fabfaa884d4138f99d0ffc734\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml
Error:(9, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').
C:\Users\Farzin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-11.8.0.aar\816b583fabfaa884d4138f99d0ffc734\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml
Error:(16, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_disabled_color_18').
C:\Users\Farzin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-11.8.0.aar\816b583fabfaa884d4138f99d0ffc734\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml
Error:(9, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').
C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml
Error:(9, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').
C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml
Error:(16, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_disabled_color_18').
C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml
Error:(9, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\SDK\sdk_1\build-tools\27.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\SDK\sdk_1\platforms\android-27\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.parsdigit.helsa -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\SDK\sdk_1\build-tools\27.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\SDK\sdk_1\platforms\android-27\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.parsdigit.helsa -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\Helsa\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\SDK\sdk_1\build-tools\27.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 31s
Information:10 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

[image]

I also tried changing the play-services versions as suggested by some posts on SOF and got these errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:sidemenulibrary:generateDebugSources, :sidemenulibrary:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :sidemenulibrary:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
C:\Users\Farzin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-11.8.0.aar\816b583fabfaa884d4138f99d0ffc734\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml
Error:(9, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').
C:\Users\Farzin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-11.8.0.aar\816b583fabfaa884d4138f99d0ffc734\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml
Error:(16, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_disabled_color_18').
C:\Users\Farzin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-11.8.0.aar\816b583fabfaa884d4138f99d0ffc734\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml
Error:(9, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').
C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\androidTest\debug\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml
Error:(9, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').
C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\androidTest\debug\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml
Error:(16, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_disabled_color_18').
C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\androidTest\debug\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml
Error:(9, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\SDK\sdk_1\build-tools\27.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\SDK\sdk_1\platforms\android-27\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\manifest\androidTest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\androidTest\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\generated\source\r\androidTest\debug -F C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\res\androidTest\debug\resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_ -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug --no-version-vectors}
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\SDK\sdk_1\build-tools\27.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\SDK\sdk_1\platforms\android-27\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\manifest\androidTest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\androidTest\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\generated\source\r\androidTest\debug -F C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\res\androidTest\debug\resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_ -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\Farzin\Desktop\MyProject\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug --no-version-vectors}
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\SDK\sdk_1\build-tools\27.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 18s
Information:10 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Here is my Gradle.app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
        {
            compileSdkVersion 27
            buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
            defaultConfig
                    {
                        applicationId "com.parsdigit.helsa"
                        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "4af7b2c1-a1a8-4b4a-ade3-d65289b38267",
                                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
                        minSdkVersion 19
                        targetSdkVersion 27
                        versionCode 1
                        versionName "1.0"
                        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
                        multiDexEnabled true
                    }
            buildTypes
                    {
                        release
                                {
                                    minifyEnabled true
                                    shrinkResources true
                                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                                }
                    }

            packagingOptions
                    {
                        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
                        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
                        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
                        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
                        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
                        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
                        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
                        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
                    }

            lintOptions
                    {
                        checkReleaseBuilds false
                    }
            dexOptions
            {
                preDexLibraries = false
            }
        }

dependencies
        {
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.+')
            compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
            compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'
            compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.4'
            compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
            compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
            compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
            compile 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.8.1@aar'
            compile 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:1.0.3'
            compile 'com.kennyc:snackbar:2.5'
            compile 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
            compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
            compile 'com.fujiyuu75:sequent:0.2.1'
            compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
            compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.10@aar'
            compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0'
            compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.2.0'
            compile 'cn.lightsky.infiniteindicator:library:1.2.2'
            compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.+'
            compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
            compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
            compile 'com.github.wooplr:Spotlight:1.2.3'
            compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
            compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1'
            compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
            compile project(':sidemenulibrary');
            compile ('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.1@aar')
            {
                transitive = true;
            }
            compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
            compile 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
            compile 'com.nex3z:notification-badge:0.3.0'
            compile 'com.github.Shashank02051997:FancyGifDialog-Android:1.1'
            compile 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:1.+'
            compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.8'
            compile 'com.github.blennerSilva:AwesomeDialog:2.0.5'
            compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
            compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
            compile 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
            compile 'com.github.RobertApikyan:SegmentedControl:release_1.0.1'
            compile 'com.github.skydoves:powermenu:2.0.1'
            compile 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:1.4.1'
            compile 'com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.7.2'
            compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
            compile 'com.github.Mostafa-MA-Saleh:EditCredit:1.5.0'
        }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Services Library update and missing symbol @integer/google\_play\_services\_version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843784/google-play-services-library-update-and-missing-symbol-integer-google-play-serv)

Comment: have you declared google_api_key(meta data) in manifest

Comment: Yes I have done so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually You Need To Delete All Gradle Cache And Rebuild It Again By Android Studio.

Also Suggest To Remove Your Android Studio And Run Your New Android Studio As Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'` - I had the same problem, it worked for me.