# Android file crunching error

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I am creating a simple project .When I try to run the project,I get the following exception.I have looked into stack overflow questions,but did not find the solution.

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

Comment: are you using image files

Comment: yes, I am using image files

Comment: I tried to change the name of the image file,but the  error is still present

Comment: There are jpg and png files

Comment: refer to solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa

Comment: It says the images in mipmap are not png files.I deleted them, now the error is gone