# Error due to nine-patch

Tags: android, nine-patch

Get this error after i convert nine-patch from png. I see your previous answers on the same problem but didn't get the result help me.

Its my error log:

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details    
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

And from here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "kliff.communitydesigns"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
} dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

}
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa

Comment: as i add abc.9.png its create problems without it my project run flawlessly.but its simple image.i want 9 patch.

Comment: thanks bro i have solve this error. Its due to my custom made 9 patch thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arise may be you are creating your own 9patch .. checkout following [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)  and create your own 9 patch as given in this tutorial

[Canvas and Drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

Comment: thanks....i have this problem from last week now i solve it by considering your answer...