# How to Solve This Error abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> Error:Failed to crunch file
>   C:\Users\Jaymin\Downloads\MyScriptCalculator_v1.2.2.479\MyScript_ATK-android-2.2\samples\SingleCharWidgetSample\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png
>   into
>   C:\Users\Jaymin\Downloads\MyScriptCalculator_v1.2.2.479\MyScript_ATK-android-2.2\samples\SingleCharWidgetSample\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png

Comment: remove digit from image name.

Comment: can't allow Digit. Remove 9 .`Clean-Rebuild`

Comment: But Inside My drawable this image are not existing it is Sdk Compiler Error

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33284865/6416089

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be 2 cases(As far as I know),

1. You have tried to convert image type just by changing their extensions.
2. Your project location is too deep.

We can discard 1st option as you have already said that you don't have these images. 
For 2nd option, try to move you project in root folder (c:\project or d:\project) & manually delete your intermediate folder & then build your project again.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank it is HelpFul I solve This Via Change Location Of My Project  and remove other project

Comment: Ideally there shouldn't be a limit to how long a path can be. I hope this can be addressed soon.