# Error while gradle sync

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

When I Sync Project with Gradle Files i got this error.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\layout-v16\notification_template_custom_big.xml
Error:(69, 37) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/notification_template_part_chronometer').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\layout-v21\notification_template_custom_big.xml
Error:(62, 37) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/notification_template_part_chronometer').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_btn_check_material.xml
Error:(18, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015').
Error:(19, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_btn_radio_material.xml
Error:(18, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015').
Error:(19, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_edit_text_material.xml
Error:(24, 63) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(25, 93) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(26, 33) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable-v21\abc_edit_text_material.xml
Error:(24, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(29, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(33, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_dark.xml
Error:(20, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:(21, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:(22, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark').
Error:(23, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_light.xml
Error:(20, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:(21, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:(22, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light').
Error:(23, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_dark.xml
Error:(22, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:(23, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:(24, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark').
Error:(25, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_light.xml
Error:(22, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:(23, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:(24, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light').
Error:(25, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml
Error:(23, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_star_half_black_36dp').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_material.xml
Error:(23, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_star_half_black_48dp').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_small_material.xml
Error:(21, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_star_half_black_16dp').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_seekbar_thumb_material.xml
Error:(20, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_control_off_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(24, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_control_off_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(28, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005').
Error:(32, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_000').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_seekbar_track_material.xml
Error:(19, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(26, 41) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(36, 41) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_switch_thumb_material.xml
Error:(18, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012').
Error:(19, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_tab_indicator_material.xml
Error:(18, 59) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\abc_textfield_search_material.xml
Error:(18, 87) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(19, 89) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(20, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(21, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\notification_bg.xml
Error:(22, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/notification_bg_normal_pressed').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\notification_bg_low.xml
Error:(21, 59) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/notification_bg_low_pressed').
Error:(22, 59) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/notification_bg_low_normal').
C:\Users\fcnak\.android\build-cache\9d6d7cc45db11cdfb28569abc01d247babc161b8\output\res\drawable\notification_tile_bg.xml
Error:(21, 18) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/notify_panel_notification_icon_bg').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout-v16\notification_template_custom_big.xml
Error:(69, 37) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/notification_template_part_chronometer').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout-v21\notification_template_custom_big.xml
Error:(62, 37) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/notification_template_part_chronometer').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_btn_check_material.xml
Error:(18, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015').
Error:(19, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_btn_radio_material.xml
Error:(18, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015').
Error:(19, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_edit_text_material.xml
Error:(24, 63) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(25, 93) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(26, 33) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-v21\abc_edit_text_material.xml
Error:(24, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(29, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(33, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_dark.xml
Error:(20, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:(21, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:(22, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark').
Error:(23, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_light.xml
Error:(20, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:(21, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:(22, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light').
Error:(23, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_dark.xml
Error:(22, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:(23, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:(24, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark').
Error:(25, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_light.xml
Error:(22, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:(23, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:(24, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light').
Error:(25, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml
Error:(23, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_star_half_black_36dp').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_ratingbar_material.xml
Error:(23, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_star_half_black_48dp').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_ratingbar_small_material.xml
Error:(21, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_star_half_black_16dp').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_seekbar_thumb_material.xml
Error:(20, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_control_off_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(24, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_control_off_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(28, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005').
Error:(32, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_000').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_seekbar_track_material.xml
Error:(19, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(26, 41) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(36, 41) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_switch_thumb_material.xml
Error:(18, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012').
Error:(19, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_tab_indicator_material.xml
Error:(18, 59) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_textfield_search_material.xml
Error:(18, 87) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(19, 89) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(20, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:(21, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\notification_bg.xml
Error:(22, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/notification_bg_normal_pressed').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\notification_bg_low.xml
Error:(21, 59) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/notification_bg_low_pressed').
Error:(22, 59) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/notification_bg_low_normal').
C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\notification_tile_bg.xml
Error:(21, 18) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/notify_panel_notification_icon_bg').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 45.089 secs
>   Information:99 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console.

My activity_main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fishPriceList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And container_fish.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivFish"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="fish name"
        android:id="@+id/textFishName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivFish"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textPrice"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="price"
        android:id="@+id/textPrice"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textSize"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textFishName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivFish"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivFish"
        android:textColor="#666"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="sd"
        android:id="@+id/textType"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textSize"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivFish"
        android:textColor="#666"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please Help Me Fast. I Will be very thankful to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your app level gradle file ?

Comment: Sir, Pls shorten your project dir name...

"C:\Users\fcnak\Desktop\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\fetch-json-data-in-android-and-display-with-recyclerview-master\Android\JsonExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml"

You yourself can see its too long to be processed.      https://stackoverflow.com/a/41695230/5672138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if you have all respective files in the `drawable` folder
2. If you have all the files in `drawable` folder, deleting `.gradle` folder from project parent directory & then restart your Android Studio using `Invalidate caches/restart` option from File menu

Comment: This method is not work for me please help me fast and thanks.

Comment: The addition after "or" might have helped him resolving his error.

Comment: The drawables mentioned in the question are defined in the appcompat-v7 support library.  Why do they need to be in the drawable folder?