# Jenkins Gradle app:mergeDebugResources Unable to open PNG file

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I am able gradle build from Android Studio and cmd. But this issue is only coming in Jenkins while building. This issue didn't come in Mac Jenkins setup, but is coming in my Windows setup.

Below is my gradle setting.

[image]

:app:mergeBetaDebugResources

```
AAPT: \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.android\build-cache\671e94b2d47b0ef7a24e43f8814a29b911cc4872\output\res\drawable-ldrtl-mdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT: \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.android\build-cache\7dc509eb0db17265925a5800b67445547ef97697\output\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT: \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.android\build-cache\671e94b2d47b0ef7a24e43f8814a29b911cc4872\output\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
:app:mergeBetaDebugResources FAILED
```

Comment: is your issue id fixed ? I still got the same error while disabling cache.

Comment: Yes. Ygor' answer did help me. add android.enableBuildCache=false in your gradle.properties

Comment: I had the same issue with a Team City build.  The accepted answer from Ygor did the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is because of the new feature of build-cache. It is using the default build-cache folder which is a long path. You can disable build-cache by adding android.enableBuildCache=false to you gradle.properties or set the build-cache path. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache.html

Comment: Disabling buildcache can hurt you development productivity. Try setting the environment variable GRADLE_USER_HOME in jenkins to another folder like c:/Users/someuser

Comment: @CassioLandim has the correct answer! I've had this issue on Jenkins for weeks! thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

`:app:generateReleaseResources` those who encountered the error must add following line to `gradle.properties` after gradle3.x

```
android.enableBuildCache=false
android.enableAapt2=true
```

Answer (score 0):

`vi gradle.properties`

android.buildCacheDir=C:/Users/Administrator/.android/build-cache

Answer (score -1):

@CassioLandim is absolutely correct, and thank you so much. This bug troubles me almost a week.

Disabling buildcache can hurt you development productivity. Try setting the environment variable GRADLE_USER_HOME in jenkins to another folder like c:/Users/someuser

Occasionally find an easy way, job -> config -> build, hook Force GRADLE_USER_HOME GRADLE_USER_HOME
[image GRADLE_USER_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0DLz.png)

Comment: `Force GRADLE_USER_HOME` will download another Gradle files which means you will ended up having multiple of Gradle dist folder on each project which is awful and waste of disk space. Not a good solution.