# Some file crunching failed AAPT err(Facade for 609828450)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting this error in newly created project.

```
> Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources] Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details Information:BUILD FAILED
```

In Log detail error is like following.

```
> 
> 
> 
> AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_normal.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_focused_holo.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_normal.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2124296350): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_focused_holo.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_focused_holo.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1998280498): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_normal.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 609828450): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1015590520): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_focused_holo.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1480126735): \\?\E:\Android\WiFiP2P\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: I have similar problem and reason behind this long path to crunch image . So please place your project directly to your drive like D/YourProject/

Comment: These are system generated images, I haven't added any image apart from default icon.

Comment: Clear your project and than try may be it help you. Review this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556280/android-studio-unable-to-open-png-file

Comment: Cleaning & Rebuilding isn't working.

Comment: Answered here and it works : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686955/529442

Answer (score 1):

I just had this today.  Go to File -> Settings, search for "compiler".  In the "Command-line options" box enter `--info`.  Run the build again and among the copious output will be the specific file that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem. It was due to default long path for caches.

Try adding the following Environmental variable in jenkins configuration.

```
 GRADLE_USER_HOME
 C:\Gradle\
```