# Gradle build fails in Jenkins because of AppCompat-v7 9 patch images but passes when built locally

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

After upgrading gradle version:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}
```

Out jenkins build started failing. But the build still succeed in local machines. The error is as below:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\anim\abc_slide_out_bottom.xml: error: file not found.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_star_black_36dp.png: error: file not found.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\color-v23\abc_color_highlight_material.xml: error: file not found.
```

And there are another set of errors as below:

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: 
AAPT err(Facade for 26900479): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2056119429): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2056119429): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1666675794): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2056119429): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 26900479): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 26900479): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 812880108): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2051797348): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 812880108): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 26900479): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 26900479): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_focused_holo.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 26900479): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar\6abe4391fc97307e05e4ad56d2401e4b\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
```

I tried many solutions suggested by many SO questions, but nothing worked. Below are the solutions I tried.

```
1. Changed the build directory thinking the path is too long for Windows.
2. Disabled build cache in gradle.properties.
3. AAPT2 made it to true and false for checking whether that is causing.
```

Comment: have you tried with invalidate cache and restart option ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Gradle app:mergeDebugResources Unable to open PNG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674890/jenkins-gradle-appmergedebugresources-unable-to-open-png-file)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found the answer and verified it was correct.

Disabling buildcache can hurt you development productivity. Try setting the environment variable GRADLE_USER_HOME in jenkins to another folder like c:/Users/someuser

Answer (score 0):

yeah, having the same issue i also tried these 3 solutions to bypass the problem (as author described) - and they all had NO positive result.

what did help me - changing environmental variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` in jenkins settings for project to another folder (in my case it was C:\temp\jenkins). thank you, @Raul Yang!

that helped for `app:mergeDebugResources` gradle (v5.2) task to be successfully completed while running it in Jenkins.