# APK build failed with gradlew.bat assembleDebug command throught Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, build.gradle, gradlew

As a newbie with JENKINS, I'm starting with building a debug version apk of a simple HelloWorld android project. Running the "gradlew.bat assembleDebug" on the local project folder works fine and I'm getting the .apk.But when it comes to Jenkins the build fails.
JENKINS configuration is of the following :
[image]

[image]

After the failure of build here is the error I'm getting on the output console :
[image]
[image]

After consulting answers about the error I added the fellowing line to the gradle.properties file :

> android.enableAapt2=false

But the issue is still persistant.
I had some doughts about the gitignore properties which are like this :

```
*.iml
 /local.properties
 /.idea/workspace.xml
 /.idea/libraries
 .DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
.gradle/
bin/
```

Any help or a new way to achieve a clean build would be appreciated.

Comment: I found similar issue, can u try the solution [Jenkins Gradle app:mergeDebugResources Unable to open PNG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674890/jenkins-gradle-appmergedebugresources-unable-to-open-png-file)