# Unable to build APK file on Jenkins (react native)

Tags: react-native, jenkins, aapt

I'm trying to integrate my react native project with Jenkins and i have successfully integrate my repository.
Unit tests are executing fine and gives positive result by using `npm test` but when i tried to build an **apk** file by using `npm run build-android-dev_windows` it gives following error. 
Can someone help on this?

```
:app:mergeDebugResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 2089038429) : No Delegate set : lost message:\\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.0.1.aar\0f905b376ce921568ac300b16c931219\res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2089038429) : No Delegate set : lost message:\\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.0.1.aar\0f905b376ce921568ac300b16c931219\res\drawable-hdpi\abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2089038429) : No Delegate set : lost message:\\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-23.0.1.aar\0f905b376ce921568ac300b16c931219\res\drawable-mdpi\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 2089038429) : No Delegate set : lost message:\\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\007e2a245d6f6256c0c6fa8758345ca4\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
```

Comment: did you try cleaning the grade cache in android?

Comment: Yes i have tried,this only happens once i run "npm run build-android-dev_windows" on Jenkins ,in locally it is working fine.

Comment: Looks like the image assets you've used is not able to open? Do they exist?

Comment: Yes they exists!

Comment: Looks like this question also has same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686955/1289629