# Failed to linking references getting AAPT2 error every time i build the code

Tags: android

**Cannot able to build the app getting this error, before it was running fine**

```
app/src/main/res    
values/arrays.xml   
error: resource drawable/ic_menu_home_selection (aka com.beeland.consumer:drawable/ic_menu_home_selection) not found.   
error: resource drawable/ic_menu_my_account_selection (aka com.beeland.consumer:drawable/ic_menu_my_account_selection) not found.   
error: resource drawable/ic_menu_offers_selection (aka com.beeland.consumer:drawable/ic_menu_offers_selection) not found.   
error: resource drawable/ic_menu_about_us_selection (aka com.beeland.consumer:drawable/ic_menu_about_us_selection) not found.   
error: resource drawable/ic_menu_settings_selection (aka com.beeland.consumer:drawable/ic_menu_settings_selection) not found.   
error: resource drawable/ic_menu_contact_us_selection (aka com.beeland.consumer:drawable/ic_menu_contact_us_selection) not found.   
error: resource drawable/ic_menu_logout (aka com.beeland.consumer:drawable/ic_menu_logout) not found.   
null    
failed linking references.
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.beeland.consumer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.BeeLandConsumerApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashStyle">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Cannot figure out what exactly the problem here, not able to build the code, before it was working fine but suddenly it stopped working don't know why.

Comment: post your `manifest` file@Yash Parikh

Comment: @Dhanshri have added the `Manifest.xml` file

Comment: remove </activity> closing tag.It is declare two times.@Yash Parikh

Comment: What are the type of images are you using?Is it `png` or `jpg`?@Yash Parikh

Comment: png and 9-patch

Comment: Did you change the format of images manually?There are two problem the image format changing manually or long path issue.See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa @Yash Parikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`Android Asset Packaging Tool (AAPT)`**](https://elinux.org/Android_aapt) can also compile resources into binary assets. Build scripts and IDE plugins utilize this tool to package the apk file that constitutes an Android application.

At first, **REMOVE** one **`</activity>`** tag.

```
 </activity>
         </activity>
```

Then Check your **`drawables`** folder and make sure resources present or not in your all **drawable** folder.

Add below in your `build.gradle` section.

```
android 
{ 
   aaptOptions
   {
   cruncherEnabled = false
   } 
}
```

Finally **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Comment: Hi Amiya, thanks for the answer, checked the resources and yes they are present in the Drawable folder i tried to build but no luck...

Comment: @YashParikh Kindly provide logcat please.

Comment: this is not the runtime error so no logcat, i have shared the error getting at compile time

Comment: @YashParikh Let me inform.

Comment: Hey... Got the solution... it was problem with my image file... it was not registered in the R.java file somehow, but replacing it again solved my problem.... anyways thanks for the help :)